# Check if a function is using a callback or returning a value

Tags: javascript, callback

In some libraries/frameworks documentations, it tells you that you can use synchronous or asynchronous function.

For example, in [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators) it says:

> Custom validators can also be asynchronous. If your validator function takes 2 arguments, mongoose will assume the 2nd argument is a callback.

So basically when you define a function like this:

```
function(a){
    return false;
}
```

Mongoose will consider it as synchronous, but we define it like this:

```
function(a,callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(false);
    },5000)
}
```

It will be taken as asynchronous code.

I've noticed the same thing with [Mocha testing framework](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code), in the documentation is says:

> Testing asynchronous code with Mocha could not be simpler! Simply invoke the callback when your test is complete. By adding a callback (usually named done) to it(), Mocha will know that it should wait for this function to be called to complete the test.

---

My question is: **How do they do this? How would you know when calling a function whether it takes 1 or 2 arguments?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd just check the arguments

```js
function something(arg1, arg2) {
    if (typeof arg2 === 'function') {
        console.log(arg1 + ' has callback');
    } else {
        console.log(arg1 + ' does not have callback');
    }
}

something('call 1'); // no callback

something('call 2', function() {}); // has callback
```

To check how many arguments a function is expecting, you'd use [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

> `length` is a property of a function object, and indicates how many
>   arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters.
>   This number excludes the rest parameter and only includes parameters
>   before the first one with a default value. By contrast,
>   arguments.length is local to a function and provides the number of
>   arguments actually passed to the function.

```js
console.log((function()        {}).length); /* 0 */
console.log((function(a)       {}).length); /* 1 */
console.log((function(a, b)    {}).length); /* 2 etc. */
```

Comment: @adeneo you cannot change into function

Answer (score 4):

> How do they do this? How would you know when calling a function whether it takes 1 or 2 arguments?

You can figure this out using `functionname.length`.

```
function some(a,b,c){
    return false;
}

function somethingElse(a){
   return false;
}

some.length //returns 3.
somethingElse.length //returns 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var func= function(a,b){

}
console.log(func.length);
```